# Fragment ListView doubles on return

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, android-listview, android-adapter

I use a custom adapter for my ListView in a fragment. When I go to a second fragment and press the back key to go back, though, my list doubles (everything from my ArrayList is added again to the listView). This happens everytime I go to my second fragment and come back (the ArrayList gets appended to the back again). I tried checking if the adapter is null, but apparently it's always null when you go back to the fragment.

I tried moving my code into the `onResume()` and the `onStart()` functions from this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446361/android-listview-duplicates-itself-when-i-launch-a-new-activity-and-press-back], but that doesn't fix my code :(

In addition, I tried adding `arr.clear()` and `notifyAll()` in `onPause` but that just breaks my code (cannot transition into second fragment). Same with `onStop()`

```
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        for (int i = 0; i < device_names.length; i++) {
            arr.add(device_names[i]);
        }

        final ListView list = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
        CustomListView customAdapter = new CustomListView(context, arr);
        if (list.getAdapter() == null) {
            Log.i("SAKEGA", String.valueOf(list.getAdapter()));
            Log.i("SAKEGA", "it's null");
        } else {
            Log.i("SAKEGA", "it's not null waaaaaaaaaah");
            list.setAdapter(null);
        }
        list.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        Log.i("SAKEGA", "HMPH");
        Button tv = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.add_devices_text);
        ImageButton add = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.add);
        tv.setOnClickListener(add_device_click); // this click listener calls the 2nd fragment
        add.setOnClickListener(add_device);
    }

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scanneractivity, null);
    return root;
}
```

What I would like to do is, once we go back to the fragment, I clear the ListView and repopulate the listView with the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Try to **create an empty array list** in the `onStart()` itself as you wrote your code there. what you are doing is you are persisting that array and every time you comeback its loading your array again making the entries again